# Dimensions of input not matching while training standard UNet model and doing keras data_augmentation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, data-augmentation

I am trying to train a standard UNet model with the help of Data Augmentation in Keras. But I am getting the following error and I am unable to solve it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

# we create two instances with the same arguments
data_gen_args = dict(featurewise_center=True,
                     featurewise_std_normalization=True,
                     rotation_range=90,
                     width_shift_range=0.1,
                     height_shift_range=0.1,
                     zoom_range=0.2)
image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)
mask_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)
# Provide the same seed and keyword arguments to the fit and flow methods
seed = 1
image_datagen.fit(train_data, augment=True, seed=seed)
mask_datagen.fit(train_label, augment=True, seed=seed)
image_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    training_loc,
    class_mode=None,
    seed=seed)
mask_generator = mask_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    training_label_loc,
    class_mode=None,
    seed=seed)
# combine generators into one which yields image and masks
train_generator = zip(image_generator, mask_generator)

model.fit( train_generator, steps_per_epoch=len(train_data)/20, epochs=50)
```

My train_data and train_label has been generated in the following way:

```
for i in training_images:
    im = plt.imread(training_loc + i)
    label = plt.imread(training_label_loc + i.split('_')[0] + '_manual1.gif')
    train_data.append(cv2.resize(im, (desired_size, desired_size)))
    temp = cv2.resize(label, (desired_size, desired_size))
    train_label.append(temp)

train_label = np.array(train_label)
train_label = np.reshape(train_label, (20,128,128,1))
```

So, train_label size is  (20, 128, 128, 1) and train_data size is (20, 128, 128,3)

I am getting the following error:

```
Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.
Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.
Epoch 1/50
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-8a4af2dc5c51> in <module>()
     25 train_generator = zip(image_generator, mask_generator)
     26 
---> 27 model.fit( train_generator, steps_per_epoch=len(train_data)/20, epochs=50)

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     62     if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError:  ConcatOp : Dimensions of inputs should match: shape[0] = [0,128,16,16] vs. shape[1] = [0,128,32,32]
     [[node model/concatenate/concat (defined at <ipython-input-11-8a4af2dc5c51>:27) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_2908]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

Edit:
This is the model of the U-Net I am trying to use.

```
import tensorflow as tf


IMG_WIDTH = 128
IMG_HEIGHT = 128
IMG_CHANNELS = 3


#Build the model
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_CHANNELS))
s = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x / 255)(inputs)

#Contraction path
c1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(s)
c1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c1)
c1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c1)
p1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c1)

c2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(p1)
c2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c2)
c2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c2)
p2 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c2)
 
c3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(p2)
c3 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c3)
c3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c3)
p3 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c3)
 
c4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(p3)
c4 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c4)
c4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c4)
p4 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(c4)
 
c5 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(p4)
c5 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(c5)
c5 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c5)

#Expansive path 
u6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c5)
u6 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u6, c4])
c6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(u6)
c6 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c6)
c6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c6)
 
u7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c6)
u7 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u7, c3])
c7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(u7)
c7 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c7)
c7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c7)
 
u8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c7)
u8 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u8, c2])
c8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(u8)
c8 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c8)
c8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c8)
 
u9 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(16, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c8)
u9 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u9, c1], axis=3)
c9 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(u9)
c9 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c9)
c9 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c9)
 
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid')(c9)
 
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

Comment: Looks to me more like a problem within the model? Could you add your model implementation?

Comment: Check your model summary. This error indicates, in concatenate layers in Unet, it gets an input with (16,16) and the other input (32,32). Since, for concatenation, all dimension should be equal except the one you gonna concat, it raises the error.

Comment: @RamtinNouri This is the implementation of the model I am trying to use. I added it after the edit. And thank you so much for taking the time to reply.

Comment: @Kaveh thank you so much for answering. But I am somewhat still at a loss to understand. I am going to try understanding more about the layers. Then.

Comment: @Soumee Is all of your images in the desired size? You just set resize for elements in `training_data` and `training_label`. Does using them in `generator.fit()` means generator in `flow_from_directory` applies resize for each image in the directory? One other thing I think you should modify in your question, is that you have said your desired shape is (512,512), but you have set image width and height in model definition (128,128).

Comment: @Kaveh Thank you so much. I finally got it right. The img_width and height needed to be set to 256 to match that of my unet. I am still facing problems because of low-contrast images. But this problem got solved.